# "Deep" Convert an Object

Tags: c#

I have the following method that I can use to convert an object to a given type:

```
public static TTarget Convert<TTarget>(object source) where TTarget : new()
{
    var target = new TTarget();

    Type targetType = typeof (TTarget);
    foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (!sourceProperty.CanRead || (sourceProperty.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0))
            continue;

        PropertyInfo targetProperty = targetType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);

        if ((targetProperty != null) && (targetProperty.CanWrite))
            targetProperty.SetValue(target, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
    }
    return target;
}
```

It works fine for simple classes with properties being value types and so on, but complex properties, that need to be mapped to another class, it's not quite clear how to go about it. If I store the mappings into a static property:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Type> Mappings;

static TypeConverter()
{
    Mappings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
        {
            {typeof (DbSpace), typeof (DmsSpace)},
            {typeof (DbDirectory), typeof (DmsDirectory)},
            {typeof (DbFile), typeof (DmsFile)}
        };
}
```

I don't seem to find a way to find a way to utilize this information for converting complex properties.
How do I go about using the above mappings to convert complex properties?

The crux of the problem is:  How can I call `new` if I only have a `Type` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Activator.CreateInstance(type)`, here's a link to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) for those that think my answer was not "elaborate" enough (got 3 downvotes for a spot-on as-short-as-necessary answer)...

Have you also looked at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: just use auto mapper , make property names exactly the same where possible

Comment: Perfect both approaches were successful. I have posted my answers below just so other may use them if they need to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use many *serializers* (JavaScriptSerializer, XmlSerializer, Json.Net etc.)
 to make a "deep convert" of your object as long as the propery names match.

I will give an example using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
var class1 = new Class1() { Property = "a", SubProperty = new SubClass1() { SubProperty = "b" } };
var class2 = Convert<Class2>(class1);


public static TTarget Convert<TTarget>(object source) where TTarget : new()
{
    var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = ser.Serialize(source);
    return ser.Deserialize<TTarget>(json);
}
```

.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public SubClass1 SubProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass1
{
    public string SubProperty { get; set; }
}


public class Class2
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public SubClass2 SubProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass2
{
    public string SubProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `Activator.CreateInstance`:

```
public static class TypeConverter
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Type> Mappings;

    static TypeConverter()
    {
        Mappings = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
            {
                {typeof (DbSpace), typeof (DmsSpace)},
                {typeof (DbDirectory), typeof (DmsDirectory)},
                {typeof (DbFile), typeof (DmsFile)}
            };
    }

    public static object Convert(object source, Type targetType)
    {
        var target = Activator.CreateInstance(targetType);

        foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (!sourceProperty.CanRead || (sourceProperty.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0))
                continue;

            PropertyInfo targetProperty = targetType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);

            object value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null);

            if ((targetProperty != null) && (targetProperty.CanWrite))
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    Type valueType = value.GetType();
                    Type mappedTypeKey = Mappings.Keys.FirstOrDefault(valueType.IsAssignableFrom);
                    if (mappedTypeKey != null)
                    {
                        targetProperty.SetValue(target, Convert(value, Mappings[mappedTypeKey]), null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        targetProperty.SetValue(target, value, null);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    targetProperty.SetValue(target, null, null);
                }
            }

        }
        return target;
    }

    public static TTarget Convert<TTarget>(object source) where TTarget : class, new()
    {
        return Convert(source, typeof (TTarget)) as TTarget;
    }
}
```

Sample code using my TypeConverter class:

```
spaces = ctx.DbSpaces.Include("Root").ToList().Select(TypeConverter.Convert<DmsSpace>).ToList();
```

Solution using AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DbSpace, DmsSpace>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DbSpace, IDmsSpace>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DbDirectory, DmsDirectory>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DbDirectory, IDmsDirectory>();
```

Sample code using AutoMapper:

```
spaces = ctx.DbSpaces.Include("Root").ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<DmsSpace>).ToList();
```